# Using foldr to return the suffixes of a list

Tags: sml, smlnj, fold

I need to return the suffix of a list and can't seem to solve it.

Given a list `[1,2,3]`, the function should return `[[3],[2,3],[1,2,3]]`. We're supposed to solve using foldr and an auxiliary function.

Comment: Think about it this way: `foldr` will present you with each item of the input list in reverse order, as well as your accumulated result so far. What do you have to do, if you had a list of the first `n` suffixes of your list, and the `n+1`th element (counting from the end) to compute the `n+1`th suffix?

Answer (score 1):

Here is @Landei's solution in SML syntax:

```
fun suffixes xs = 
   let 
      fun f (y, []) = [[y]]
        | f (y, yss as (ys::_)) = (y::ys)::yss
   in
      rev (foldr f [] xs)
   end
```

I assume that you're allowed to use `rev` function from [SML Basis Library](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list.html). Otherwise, implementing such a function should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

[1,2,3,4] will return [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4],[3,4],[4]] :

```
fun myfun1 l = foldr(fn (a,b)=> if a=nil then [] else a::b@myfun1(tl(l)))[] [l]
```

[1,2,3,4] will return [[4],[3,4],[2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]] :

```
fun myfun2 l = foldr(fn (a,b)=> if a=nil then [] else myfun2(tl(l))@a::b)[] [l]
```

Answer (score 0):

Haskell would be:

```
suffixes = reverse . foldr f [] where
  f y [] = [[y]]
  f y (yss@(ys:_)) = (y:ys) : yss
```

I don't know SML, but the solution should be similar

Comment: I added a translation of your function to SML. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks! This is indeed very similar (and would be even more if I had used `let` as well).